# How does VS 2019 select for which .asm file to create a listing file

Tags: visual-studio, masm

I have a standard (?) project (vcxproj) with multiple .asm files in Visual Studio 2019 Community 16.6.

In Configuration properties->MASM I have not set anything
[image: No Explicit options for creating a .lst file for the project]

Still the .lst file is created for the project. So, there must be some "hidden" defaults somewhere. However, even if I set them explicitly - there is no setting as to for which .asm file the listing file should be created.

I could not find anything as to the default implicit behavior / explicit behavior of choice of one .asm file over another. Logically, it would be the file containing the entry point in x86-32bit "end main", but that's not the case. Also, is there a way to generate .lst next to the .obj file for all .asm files in a given project.

Comment: `different options` means different between configurations and platforms, not source files. To change the settings for an individual file, open the properties dialog for that file, not the entire project.

Answer (score 0):

right for me:

1. Open Project ,
2. Create a file (*).asm AND  write  code
3. Go to `Property` of `Project`: ( note `platform` for correct in first line - for me: `WIN32` )
4. Go to `Microsoft Macro Assembler` - `Listing file` - set `Yes(/Sg)` Enable Assembly Generated Code Listing
   and set `$(ProjectName).lst` in `Assembled Code Listing File`
5. Go to `property` of file (*).asm  do the same thing as above...

Thanks for watch